# Creating a new class object and setting variables directly - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how to efficiently create a new class object and set the variables directly.

I have a class:

```
class element_model
{
    public $sType;
    public $properties;
}
```

I have a controller in which the following function is defined:

```
public function create_element($sType, $properties)
{
    $oElement_model = new element_model($sType, $properties);
    return new element_model($sType, $properties);
}
```

But this does not returns a new element_model with properties set, it just returns an empty object.
It does not, however, throw an error.

What is the reason the function above does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass to the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the class, in PHP you should have a method in the class `__construct` :

```
class element_model
{
    public $sType;
    public $properties;

    public function __construct($type, $property)
    {
        $this->sType = $type;
        $this->properties = $property;
    }
}
```

Then you can access them (note the variables are public)

```
$elem = new element_model($sType, $properties);
$elem->sType;
```

Although in some cases it is better to encapsulate vars (declare them **private**):

```
class element_model
{
    private $sType;
    private $properties;

    public function __construct($type, $property)
    {
        $this->sType = $type;
        $this->properties = $property;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->sType;
    }

    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this->properties;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the variable through a **getter**

```
$elem = new element_model($sType, $properties);
$elem->getType(); //and
$elem->getProperty();
```

Comment: I'd be helpful to elaborate the cases in which setters/getters are useful.

Comment: @deceze, could you please tell me why you think this way?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a __construct function in your class that accepts the parameters and sets your variables. Like this:

```
class element_model{
    .
    .
    .
    public function __construct($type,$properties)
    {
        $this->sType = $type;
        $this->properties = $properties;
    }
}
```

The __construct function will be called when you create the object.

But if you want to be extra cool in programming, just define your properties as private and create getter and setter functions to access the variables of your object

```
private $sType;
public function getSType(){
   return $this->sType;
}
public function setSType($value){
    $this->sType = $value;
}
```

Comment: *"if you want to be extra cool in programming"* – wut? Naïve setters like you show are superfluous and *extra uncool*.